# How to merge a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, merge, stringbuilder

I need to merge **string1** into **string2**. How can I do it?. Please tell me how to do it.

Thank you

```
String string1 = "AAABBCCBABBBBBCCCAAABCCBAA"
```

CONVERT INTO THIS

```
 String string2 = "ABCBABCABCBA"
```

What is the available techniques to solve my problem. Which methods should I use ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried? Technique to solve the problem: search for _java string manipulation_. Try something out and come back when there is a specific problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way besides using a `StringBuilder` is to replace patterns of same characters using a regular expression:

```
String string1 = "AAABBCCBABBBBBCCCAAABCCBAA";
string1 = string1.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

The first parameter of `replaceAll` is the regex with `\\1` used to match the character matches by the group `(.)`. The second parameter is the replacement string (`$1` also matches the first group).

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant 'convert' for 'merge'
i.e., you want to eliminate duplicate characters from string1 and output it as string2 (adjacent duplicates removed)? Please correct if I didn't understand properly

Assume my understanding is correct, you could use the below pseudo-code

```
StringBuffer string2 = new StringBuffer();
prev = null;
foreach char ch  string1
    if (prev != null && ch !=prev)
        string2.append(prev);
    prev = ch;
string2.append(prev);
return string2.toString();
```